# Zend router not determining params correctly

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, routes

I have the following code:

```
$routes = array(
    'twitter_output' => new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'twitter/:username\.:format',
        array('controller' => 'twitter', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);
```

Basically I want it to match: `http://site.com/twitter/edu2004eu.json` (except not only json, maybe xml and others too).

But when I print my request object, it gives me:

```
[_params:protected] => Array ( [username\.:format] => edu2004eu.json )
```

but it should say:

```
[_params:protected] => Array ( [username] => edu2004eu, [format] => json )
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I've tried the same with a slash instead of a dot (`http://site.com/twitter/edu2004eu/json`) and it seems to be working, but I want the dot (to be cool like all APIs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the standard route type is set to use dot as a separator. You could use a regexp route instead:

```
$routes = array(
    'twitter_output' => new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        'twitter/([\w]+)\.([\w]+)',
        array('controller' => 'twitter', 'action' => 'index'),
        array(1 => 'username', 2 => 'format'),
        'twitter/%s.%s'
    )
);
```